# Ruby: Iterate over days in previous month

Tags: ruby, date

I need to be able to loop through all days of the previous month and do something with the parsed day. This is what I have so far:

```
def dateTest

    d = Date.parse(Time.now.to_s)

    from_date = Date.new(d.year, d.month - 1, 1)
    to_date = Date.new(d.year, d.month, -1)

    from_date..to_date.each do |day|
        #Do stuff with day
    end

end
```

My issue is I can't seem to get `to_date` to equal the last day of the previous month. I've read many similar questions but most of them seem more geared towards Rails, which won't help me in this case.

Comment: Note this raises an exception when `d` is in January.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
require 'date'

d = Date.today << 1 # << 1 is one month earlier
(Date.new(d.year, d.month, 1)..Date.new(d.year, d.month,-1)).each{|date| p date}
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can use `...` exclude the end value.

For example:

```
(1..5).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(1...5).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

so you can write like this:

```
if d.month != 1
   from_date = Date.new(d.year, d.month - 1, 1)
else
   from_date = Date.new(d.year-1, -1)
end
to_date = Date.new(d.year, d.month)

(from_date...to_date).map { |day| puts day}
```

output:

```
2015-04-01
2015-04-02
2015-04-03
......
2015-04-29
2015-04-30
```

Comment: Oh I see, as opposed to `..` which would include it? I think I'd prefer to reference to date explicitly rather than just 'missing' the first day of the month. Seems mistakes could me made quite easily

Comment: This is optional, as long as you understand how it works, you can use anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
require 'date'

d = Date.today << 1
start = Date.new(d.year, d.month)
(start...(start >> 1)).each { |d| p d }
  #-> #<Date: 2015-04-01 ((2457114j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
  #   #<Date: 2015-04-02 ((2457115j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
  #   ...
  #   #<Date: 2015-04-30 ((2457143j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prev_day` function can also be used:

```
require 'date'

d = Date.today

from_date = Date.new(d.year, d.month - 1, 1)
to_date = Date.new(d.year, d.month, 1).prev_day

from_date..to_date.each do |day|
    #Do stuff with day
end
```